# Override original window.navigator properties in PhantomJS script

Tags: javascript, properties, phantomjs, overriding, navigator

I need to override some window.navigator properties in my script to emulate different Navigator behavior.

```
page.onInitialized = function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {

        (function() {
                window.screen = {
                   width: 480,
                   height: 800
                };

            var fake_navigator = {};
            for (var i in navigator) {
                fake_navigator[i] = navigator[i];
            }

            fake_navigator.javaEnabled = function() { return true; };
            fake_navigator.userAgent = 'test';
            fake_navigator.platform = 'Linux armv71';
            fake_navigator.vendor = 'Google Inc';
            fake_navigator.vendorSub = 'zozo';
            fake_navigator.onLine = true;
            window.navigator = fake_navigator;  

            window.navigator.__defineGetter__("vendorSub", function(){ return 'zozo1'; });

        })();
    });
};
```

But when I load page and read e.g. window.navigator.vendorSub in javascript it still contains wrong value (default one). Whereas navigator.userAgent works fine.
So the question is about overriding onLine, connection.type and platform like properties. Why it doesn't work and how to override them? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can completely replace the `window.navigator` object, because it is tightly coupled to the browser. What you probably can do is adding and removing most (all?) of its properties according to your needs.

Comment: Well, I don't need to replace all of them.  I need to replace at least onLine, platform, vendor and userAgent.  And I can override userAgent, but not the others mentioned.

BTW, I'm speaking about running script from phantomjs, not real browser.

Comment: PhantomJS is a *real* browser in every sense of the word. It's just headless which most others aren't. As I said, PhantomJS prevents to replace root objects like `navigator`, but its properties are fair game.